# Check box selection issue in vue.js

Tags: vue.js

Please look the below image

[image]

I have two users and their allowed channels.

***My issue is :***

When I click one channel of a user, the same channel is also get checked of other user. For example:
When I click *Commissions* of user *Deepu*, the channel *Commissions* of user *Midhun* also get checked.
I have to avoid that, the clicked channel of the user should only selected, not other user's.

**I tried this**

```
<v-data-table
                :headers="headers"
                :items="UserChannels"
                :loading="datatableloading"
                class="elevation-1"
              >
                <template v-slot:items="props">
                  <td class="text-xs-left">{{ props.item.username }}</td>
                  <td class="text-xs-left">
                  <ul class="channel-listitems">
                    <li v-for="item  in Channels">
                    <input type="checkbox" class="channel-checkbox" :value="item.id" v-model="checkedChannels">
                      {{ item.channel_name }}
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                  <br>
                  <span>Checked names: {{ checkedChannels }}</span>
                  </td>
                </template>
              </v-data-table>
```

I am using **Vue.js** for doing this.

Comment: Your checkbox's `v-model` is bound to the same `checkedChannels` for each channel. I would move that prop to each `Channels` item if feasible, and then bind the checkbox's `v-model` to `item.checkedChannels`. Otherwise, I'd create a second container (array/hashmap) that maps the channel ID to the checkbox value, and then update the `v-model` to the corresponding map entry.

Comment: How does the user data looks like ? Each user should have an own "checkedChannels" field to begin with.

Comment: @PascalLamers, currently listing all channels for each user.Plan is to update depending on selection of channel. Then allowed own channel shows as checked. There should be an update button in each row. Currently am in initial stage only.

Comment: @tony19, can you share some code. it would be very helpful..

Comment: @DeepuSasidharan pls take a look at my answer and see if it helps you .

Comment: @DeepuSasidharan updated my answer, found an official solution in the Vue docs. Please take a look a accept if it helped.

Comment: @DeepuSasidharan Please accept answer if it's the correct answer or if it helped you ! Thanks !

Answer (score 3):

You can create mapping `dict` for each user Channels selection.

Please refer following codepen - https://codepen.io/Pratik__007/pen/oNgaXeJ?editors=1010

In data

```
checkedChannels:{},
```

Created

```
 created () {
    console.log(this.Channels)
    let vm = this;
    this.Users.map(function(item){
      vm.$set(vm.checkedChannels,item['name'],[])
      return item;
    })
  },
```

Answer (score 2):

The official Vue docs states, you can use v-model on multiple checkboxes using the same array. ( Docs : https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#Checkbox )

Also working example : https://codesandbox.io/s/hungry-kepler-t7mkw

### Select elements for array with checkboxes and v-model

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    
    <!-- First, iterate over all users -->
    <div v-for="(user, index) in users" class="user">
      <p class="name">{{ user.username }} - Checked Channels {{user.channels}}</p>
      
      <!-- Create checkbox for each available channel, and v-model it to user.channels -->
      <div class="channel">
        <label v-for="(channel, index) in availableChannels">
          {{channel}}
          <input type="checkbox" v-bind:value="channel" v-model="user.channels">
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "App",
  data() {
    return {
      users: [
        {
          username: "User1",
          channels: ["channel1", "channel2"]
        },
        {
          username: "User2",
          channels: ["channel3"]
        }
      ],
      availableChannels: [
        "channel1",
        "channel2",
        "channel3",
        "channel4",
        "channel5"
      ]
    };
  }
};
</script>

<style>
.user {
  min-height: 100px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  justify-items: center;
}

.name,
.channel {
  flex: 1;
}

.channel {
  min-height: 100px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
</style>
```